# Why is object.y not positioning the image in Corona SDK?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

```
displaycontent = display.newImageRect (rawdata[currentpath][3], screenW*1.1, ((screenW*1.1/1654)*rawdata[currentpath][6]))
displaycontent.anchorY = 0
displaycontent.y = screenH*0.78
```

My program loads an image from a database to be displayed on the mobile phone's screen, everything works correctly apart from being able to position it with the y coordinates.

The only thing that changes its position is the anchor point 0 puts the top of the image in the centre of the screen, and values from 0.1 - 1 all position it higher. Changing the y position via object.y has zero effect regardless of what I set it as.

(the size settings probably look a bit weird in the first line, but this is because the images are different sizes and need to show the correct proportions on different screen types).

Btw I am using a tabbar widget as the UI (in case that is relevant)

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: I am aware that displaycontent is bad name for a variable because of its similarity to things like display.contentCenterY for example, this will be changed to prevent any confusion when I look over the code in future.

Answer (score 0):

I went through my code and tried disabling sections to find the culprit and a content mask was preventing me from setting the position of the loaded images within it.

I will look over my masking code and fix it (should be straight forward now I know where the problem started).

If anyone else has a similar problem (where an image or object wont position itself on given coordinates) check your content mask as that may be the issue!